# RenderScript's Allocation.getSurface() function always complain "call to OpenGL ES API with no current context"

Tags: android, opengl-es, allocation, renderscript

I'm working with RenderScript on Android version 4.2. I was trying to create a RenderScript Allocation with the "Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT" flag. According to the document, if "Allocation.USAGE_IO_INPUT" is set, the Allocation will be used as a SurfaceTexture consumer, and the member function "getSurface()" becomes valid as well. However, when I call getSurface() function, I always get the following error message.

```
E/libEGL(31656): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

I googled a little bit and found most of the people say that such error message is caused by calling OpenGL ES API outside the GL thread. So I tried to use the following two ways suggested by what I found.

1. call getSurface() function from onSurfaceCreated() of GLSurfaceView, since it's called in the GL thread
2. Use queueEvent of GLSurfaceView to let the code to be called in the GL thread (described here: [OpenGL ES API error (no context)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8961615/opengl-es-api-error-no-context))

However, both attempt failed.

Though the program didn't crash with this error prompt and did return some surface. I met the same issue as in [Using a SurfaceTexture filled by Camera preview as Renderscript input Allocation in Jelly Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960317/using-a-surfacetexture-filled-by-camera-preview-as-renderscript-input-allocation) when calling the Allocation.ioReceive() function. The error message I got when calling ioReceive() is

```
E/SurfaceTexture(32208): [unnamed-32208-2] updateTexImage: invalid current EGLDisplay
```

So, I'm wondering what is the correct way to work with USAGE_IO_INPUT Allocation in RenderScript? Thank you very much in advance.